# How does the operating system recognize USB Rubber Ducky as a keyboard?

Tags: operating-systems

How does the operating system recognize USB Rubber Ducky as a keyboard?
Is it the USB Rubber Ducky **firmware** which tricks the OS?

More generally, the recognition of a device by the OS is made by the device firmware or not?

Comment: Because it tells the computer that it is a keyboard. The computer does not use its camera and look at the device, and say that looks like a keyboard. It just asks the device, what are you, and the device answers. So the short answer is “it recognises it as a keyboard, in the same way that it recognises all other keyboards.”, There is no trick. Well actually there is, but it is not the computer that is tricked. It is us that is tricked, because this keyboard does not look like a keyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a USB device is plugged in, the OS asks the device for its device descriptor. That includes, among some other things, the device class, subclass, vendor ID, and product ID. Device class 3 is "human interface device", this is what the Rubber Ducky tells the OS. The OS loads a generic keyboard driver, and the device can send whatever keystrokes it likes - it's indistinguishable from a real keyboard.

There is a tool for the Rubber Ducky that lets you set its VID and PID to anything you want. There is [supposed to be a way](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff539280(v=vs.85).aspx) to get the manufacturer name and device serial number, but since they're all provided by the device itself, the firmware can just lie to the OS. (Even legitimate devices sometimes leave those blank.)

In summary, you're right, the OS believes whatever the device says it is.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a quote directly from the Wiki:

> Nearly every computer including desktops, laptops, tablets and smartphones take input from Humans via Keyboards. It's why there's a specification with the ubiquitous USB standard known as HID - or Human Interface Device. Simply put, any USB device claiming to be a Keyboard HID will be automatically detected and accepted by most modern operating systems. Whether it be a Windows, Mac, Linux or Android device the Keyboard is King.

http://usbrubberducky.com/#!index.md

It identifies itself as a keyboard to the OS. A device has to identify itself in order for the OS to know what it is and what to do with it/what to expect from it. If the device doesn't identify itself, I'm not exactly sure what will happen, but the OS probably won't know what to do with it.

Comment: If you quote something to be from Wiki - you should also provide the link to it.

Comment: @Zina oh yes, sorry. Completely slipped my mind :p.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it essentially *is* a keyboard. It's just that all the keystrokes (the payload) are pre-recorded; and then rapidly (and blindly) injected by the integrated circuitry, in the exact same manner and format as would typically be expected from a traditional USB-style keyboard. That is to say, it literally sends the signal for each individual keystroke down the wire, just as if you typed it yourself.